# Spontaneous symmetry breaking in the quantum 1D XX model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, ising-model, spin-chains

The ground states of the quantum 1D Ising and Heisenberg models exhibit spontaneous magnetization. Is this also true for the 1D XX model?

Comment: Do you mean XY model?